# Virtualization Supported, Disabled for Intel Core i7 3632QM

Tags: cpu, bios, android

I have Intel Core i7 3632QM. I installed android tools and when I ran it, it said that the Virtualization is disabled. I went into the bios section and it was enabled. I have Windows 8.1.
How can I make the Android tool force/or see that the Virtualization in my bios is enabled? I also ran piriform Speccy and it shows that the Virtualization is supported, but not enabled.

Thanks,

Fadi

Comment: Related Question...http://superuser.com/questions/928071/vt-x-enabled-in-bios-but-disabled-in-windows-7

Answer (score 2):

Enter the bios and disable VTx, boot into windows, shut down and enter the bios again, enable VTx, boot into windows, see if it is enabled in the OS now.

Also check for a bios update.

http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Activating_the_Intel_VT_Virtualization_Feature

Comment: HiMoab,This did the trick. It worked. Thanks so much.

Comment: When all fails, turn off and turn on again :) Also @FadiDajani if Moab's answer solve your problem, please mark it as an answer / accepted answer.