# VirtualBox Error - VTx is disabled in the BIOS (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, bios, vt-x

this error keeps showing to me when I try to launch a VM, I saw that other people had this issue but I can't find a way to fix it.

I went to the BIOS to check is the virtualization was enabled already, I even disabled it and enabled it again as another guy said on a different topic.

In the error it says that "VT-x is disabled", but I couldn't find it on my BIOS, only the Intel Virtualization, could this be the error?
Here is the images of the error and my BIOS.

PS: Sorry if there is any mistakes on my english, english is not my native language.

[image: Image of the Virtual Box error]

[image: Image of the BIOS]

Comment: Just to clarify, Intel VT-x is the same as the virtualization option in the BIOS. This must be set to ON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VT-x enabled in BIOS, but disabled in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/928071/vt-x-enabled-in-bios-but-disabled-in-windows-7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1366264/vt-x-not-available-in-windows-10-pro-even-though-i5-6400-cpu-supports-vt-x

Comment: **Intel Virtualization is indeed VT-x**  You are receiving this message due to the fact you have a software package installed (already using the hardware virtualization.  Please edit your question and provide enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1307829/virtualbox-verr-vmx-no-vmx